# rdiff-backup not working for files only changed by content

Tags: windows, rdiff-backup

I have a file that gets changed only by content, the timestamp doesn't change.

`rdiff-backup` on Windows is recognizing this file as changed when I use the `--print-statistics` option:

```
Successful compare: rep_1/branches
changed: rep_1/branches/branches.dat
changed: rep_1/branches/names.dat
```

Then when I run the backup the changed file is omitted:

```
Incrementing mirror file E:\rtestb/rep_1/branches
Processing changed file rep_1/branches/names.dat
Incrementing mirror file E:\rtestb/rep_1/branches/names.dat
Processing changed file rep_1/info.dat
```

I guess `rdiff-backup` is just checking the timestamp in order to determine if the file is changed.

Is it possible to make `rdiff-backup` check the file hash instead of the timestamp?

Comment: `--compare-hash-at-time` command line option should help you.

Comment: but this is just a comparison, right? I think it won't make any effect during a backup, am I wrong?